# Is it safe to leave MiniProfiler's ProfiledDbConnection in production code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, linq-to-sql, profiling, mvc-mini-profiler

Given that MiniProfiler isnt actually running for non-local requests due to the following:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
            MiniProfiler.Start();
    }
```

Is it still okay then (performance-wise) to leave the use of `ProfiledDbConnection` in production code?

```
var db = new MyDataContext(new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString), MiniProfiler.Current))
```

Answer (score 6):

In short: yes.

Every page on Stack Overflow is running it, so that connection sees something like a hundred billion uses a month just here (and we're at ~2-4% CPU load at peak traffic). It's meant to be extremely low overhead and safe for production code. Compared to the trip off-box you're about to take to query SQL, Redis, etc. - the profiling bits are very minimal.

I strive to keep it small because our primary use case is Stack Overflow scale and load. The only likely way it is problematic would be to unboundedly store profiles for a large number of requests. They have to eat storage *somewhere* and that might be an issue at scale.

For Stack Overflow: we're profiling *all* requests and storing the slow ones, for further analysis and to keep an eye on problematic routes. So not only is profiled db connection present, *it's profiling*, on all requests here. I'm not trying to brag on numbers, only provide a hopefully compelling use case for: it's fine, we're slamming it hard and have a vested interest in keeping it low-overhead.